# What to do when my animation stops after 50 seconds, whereas my animation player is in active?

Tags: animation

I had an idea to make fire effects on a cube. So I created a cube; clicked F3 and activated quick smoke effect.

Then my cube started smoking.
But unfortunately it sopped after 50 seconds.

But I noticed that my animation player is in active mode.

After,when the animation player replayed the smoke effect ran only for 50 seconds and stopped again.

I also tried for quick liquid, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 3):

Check under *physic settings* > *fluid* > *cache*, the Frame End properties.
250 frames / 25 fps = 10 seconds of animation (50 seconds seems a little out of default blender settings).

[image]